# Does GA4 Explorer take the (none) values on medium and puts them randomly on other mediums or am I mistaken?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

So, basically if I go to GA4 Explorer and put Session Medium as dimension and event count as a metric, I will get a result of:

```
Session medium| Event count
Totals        | 1000
Organic       | 500
(none)        | 200
referral      | 100
email         | 200
```

But when I export the data to BigQuery and I write the query:

```
SELECT traffic_source.medium AS medium, COUNT(event_name) AS event_count
FROM
`dataset`
WHERE CAST(event_date AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 20230609 AND 20230724
GROUP BY medium
ORDER BY event_count DESC
```

I get the results of:

```
medium        | event_count
Organic       | 470   
(none)        | 270
referral      | 80     
email         | 180
```

And if I use

```
  COUNT(event_name) FROM dataset
```

and

```
 SUM(event_count)
 FROM 
(SELECT traffic_source.medium AS medium, COUNT(event_name) AS event_count
FROM
`dataset`
WHERE CAST(event_date AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 20230609 AND 20230724
GROUP BY medium
ORDER BY event_count DESC)
```

in order to get the total, in order to be sure that there isn't a total data discrepancy, the result is 1000, just like in GA4. Noted that the date range in Explorer is the same with the one written in the queries. Same thing happens with the rest of the Traffic source dimensions combined with the other metrics.